# Is there a straightforward way to get a complete working Python environment on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

By complete working environment, I mean that pip and friends should be installed and work out of the box in the powershell windows. Same for python. The necessary environment variables should be set, and so on.

By contrast, using the official python installer leaves you with an incomplete environment, where pretty much all you can do is double-click on a ".py" file, which might be enough if you just want to run python code but not if you want to write scripts on a daily basis.

So is there a straightforward and well supported way to install a python development environment on Windows?

Comment: [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads) is a very complete distribution. Give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use at work the portable distribution [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) on a computer where I don't have the local admin rights. It doesn't change the ENV variables, but otherwise it is pretty slick :

- shipped with easy_install and pip
- Qt
- IPython
- Spyder for debugging
- TortoiseHg for versionning

You just need to make your own PATHs, and you're good to go.

Comment: Could you explain the differences between WinPython and Python(X,Y)?

Comment: The two distro were created by the same person. He explain the motivations behind each version : http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/wiki/Roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

I use [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). It works decently on the Linux computers and they claim that it would be cross platform. Though I have no experience with Python on Windows I think it might be worth a try!